# Nginx Error is Resulting in 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2

I have an AWS EC2 instance which is running Ubuntu. When I go into my error logs I have this one right here. What does this mean and how can I fix it?

This is from my error.log file:

```
2019/09/05 18:01:02 [crit] 991#991: *46 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 64.223.223.8, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock:", host: "thewildwear.com"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your Nginx server not able to communicate with php7.2-fpm either the path `/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock` is not valid or the php7.2-fpm is not running.

Check if PHP is running.

```
sudo systemctl status php7.2-fpm
```

verify the path if it exist`ls -l /var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock`

If not exist then try to find the exact file under php `cd /var/run/php/` and `ls` you will see

```
php7.*-fpm.pid  php7.*-fpm.sock
```

update the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and changed `"fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;"` line to "fastcgi_pass `unix:/var/run/php/php7.{after ls}-fpm.sock;"`.

You can check this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/causefx/Organizr/issues/980) and [here](https://central.owncloud.org/t/struggling-with-nginx-configuration-with-owncloud-10-0-4-in-subdirectory/11213).

Comment: When I try to see if php is running is returns this error: Unit php7.2-fpm.service could not be found. I found my php directory under /etc/php/7.2. What should I do now?

Comment: php is not running. start the php service `sudo systemctl start php7.2-fpm`

Comment: It responds with this error: 
    `Failed to start php7.2-fpm.service: Unit php7.2-fpm.service not found.`

Comment: try the first answer and one of them will work https://serverfault.com/questions/189940/how-do-you-restart-php-fpm

Comment: It prompts me for a password, but its not working with the password I setup when I created my server. :(     `Authenticating as: Ubuntu (ubuntu) Password:`

Comment: try with sudo user so

Comment: When I use sudo `systemctl restart php-fpm.service` it says `Failed to restart php-fpm.service: Unit php-fpm.service not found.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199033/discussion-between-adiii-and-eatsleepcode).